# MYSQL suddenly uses CPU even when no one user is connected to Mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, cpu

Site is an ecommerce site: 5 Million records in table
Two servers: one for webserver and other contains mysql
Search is happenning through Sphinx server. So search queries do not come to MySQL

Mysql configuration: Dual Quad Core Zeoo 2.0, 146 GB, 16 GB RAM.
Webserver configuration: Dual Quad Core Zeoo 2.0, 146 GB, 16 GB RAM.

For past four days I find MySQL is using CPU continuously for at least 6-7 hours in a day. It becomes normal after that. Even if I restart, it doesnt stop. It again uses CPU in 2 to 3 mins. I even tried stopping Apache and made sure no one is connecting to Mysql.

Comment: Did you chack with `mysqladmin pr` what's going on ? Maybe it's rebuilding an index or repairing a corrupt table

Comment: I am not sure if table is repair. Because its working properly for atleast 12 hours. How to check if its rebuilding index.

Comment: I also took some info using SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS

Comment: I also found this in mysqld log110715 22:23:43 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_2184_2.MYI'; try to repair it
110715 22:23:49 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Disk is full writing './morecom_db/system_log.MYD' (Errcode: 28). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)
110715 22:23:49 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Retry in 60 secs. Message reprinted in 600 secs

Comment: That means your mysql server is in a very serious condition. Take it offline, get more space on the machine (it might just be the mysql tmp folder that runs out of space), repair the tables.

Comment: I can see I have more space. Space actually grows automatically and reduces automatically. I dont know why. I had only 5 GB free space and now I can see more.
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3             124G  108G  9.8G  92% /
/dev/sda1              99M   12M   82M  13% /boot
tmpfs                 7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm

Comment: I repaired the table fully still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same issue on my server and tried to do something about it. I upgraded mysql and all it did was reduce the amount of CPU used - from 100% to 55%

I `think` my issue is Leap Second related - I notice your question is 15 days after the lead second.

I found:
[EC2 Amazon Linux AMI MySQL CPU @ 62% When Idle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282376/ec2-amazon-linux-ami-mysql-cpu-62-when-idle)

Which lead me to:
[Why Does the Leap Second Cause Problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279076/why-does-the-leap-second-cause-problems)

Lastly I did the classic windows fix and rebooted the linux box - this worked (did not check if kernel had been upgraded in mean time)