# Why Does the Leap Second Cause Problems?

Tags: time, operating-system, datetime

So at this moment (but most likely not for long) Reddit, Meetup, Fark, LinkedIn, Yelp, 4Chan are all down. Netflix apparently was out for a while too.

According to Reddit's tweet, they are having issues relating to the Leap Second from 6/30/2012: https://twitter.com/redditstatus/status/219244389044731904

> "We are having some Java/Cassandra issues related to the leap second
>   at 5pm PST. We're working as quickly as we can to restore service."

Apparently, the issues affecting the other sites are all related to a leap second issue.

After reading Wikipedia article on [Leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second), I *think* I understand what leap seconds are... but what I don't get is what kind of weird behaviors can happen if leap second isn't accounted for? And how, as programmers, should we prepare for leap seconds when we code and configure servers?

I mean it's only one second isn't it?

Comment: For the record, Yelp was no longer down by the time you posted this question.

Comment: the east coast is getting hit by a big storm that is leaving millions without power and also took out a big data center used by amazon (Amazon’s Elastic Compute Cloud in North Virginia), reedit, netflix, and a lot others, this is also the reason why a lot of web sites are down today.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Certain Linux kernels (versions before 2.6.29) have [issues handling leap seconds](https://lkml.org/lkml/2009/1/2/373), to the point where [it can cause a kernel panic](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=479765). Other Linux kernels [can suffer from a livelock](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1203.1/04598.html). This obviously has detrimental effects for the system, given that it requires a reboot.

Here's [the related ServerFault question on this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/403732/anyone-else-experiencing-high-rates-of-linux-server-crashes-today), since it's really a Linux server issue.

Comment: Why? What is about a leap second that causes a kernel panic?

Comment: The kernel code that handles the leap second message from `ntp` is buggy. (If you want a more detailed explanation, I'd recommend reading the linked mailing list entries/bug reports.)

Comment: marked as correct answer, but it would be nice if the specific problem was also put in the answer! thanks @Amber !

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260310/storing-a-leap-second-in-sql-server-2008/11261135#11261135

Comment: For java related high-cpu usage. Try the ff fix. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769972

Answer (score 0):

On most systems I've seen (routers), one issue is either the uptime (time the system has been up) xor the boottime (the time the system booted) will be wrong by 1 second if a leap second was crossed.  Also, logs at 23:59:60 are wrongly stamped with 23:59:59.  Protocol timers are not affected.  NTP falls out of sync and steps the clock to correct it--this takes several minutes in accordance with NTP rules.